# Cannot save image from base64 into gallery

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

```
import {CameraPreview, CameraPreviewOptions,} from '@ionic-native/camera-preview';
import {ToastController} from "ionic-angular";
import {Base64ToGallery} from '@ionic-native/base64-to-gallery';

  private cameraPreviewOpts: CameraPreviewOptions = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: window.screen.width,
            height: window.screen.height,
            camera: 'rear',
            tapPhoto: true,
            previewDrag: true,
            toBack: true,
            alpha: 1
  };

  constructor(
              public navCtrl: NavController,
              public toastCtrl: ToastController,
              public navParams: NavParams,
              private camera: CameraPreview,
              public platform: Platform,
              private base64ToGallery: Base64ToGallery
                 ) 
  {
         var browser = this.platform.is('core');
         if (!browser) {this.camera.startCamera(this.cameraPreviewOpts);}
  }

      takePicture() {
        this.camera.takePicture({}).then((base64Data) => {
          this.base64ToGallery.base64ToGallery(base64Data).then(
            res => alert('Saved image to gallery ' + JSON.stringify(res)),
            err => alert('Error saving image to gallery ' + JSON.stringify(err))
          );
        }, (err) => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        });
      }
```

When I try to save save image in gallery then I have this error:

```
{"__zone_symbol__currentTask":{"type":"microTask","state":"notScheduled","source":"Promise.then","zone":"angular","cancelFn":null,"runCount":0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Install CameraPreview from npmjs `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera-preview`

2) put this code before @Component `declare let CameraPreview;`

3) Don't forget to allow storage access and write storage in application params or with androidPermission

3) there is my code it's work !

```
takePic(){
    const options = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: window.screen.width,
        height: window.screen.height,
        camera: CameraPreview.CAMERA_DIRECTION.FRONT, //or BACK
        toBack: true,
        tapPhoto: false,
        tapFocus: false,
        previewDrag: false,
        disableExifHeaderStripping: true
    };

    CameraPreview.startCamera(options);

    let base64option : Base64ToGalleryOptions = {
        prefix: 'img',
        mediaScanner: false
    };

    CameraPreview.takePicture({}, base64PictureData => {
        let todecode = atob(base64PictureData);

        this.base64ToGallery.base64ToGallery(btoa(todecode), base64option).then(
            res => alert('Saved image to gallery '+ JSON.stringify(res)),
            err => alert('Error saving image to gallery ' + JSON.stringify(err))
          );
    }, error =>{
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

You must start camera in background to take picture `toBack: true`, decode and encode your `base64PictureData` with `atob` & `btoa`

Your picture is now in internal storage/Pictures !

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add

> destinationType: 2

the image will save into locally and you will get a local path link.